# how to reactivate solana network after locking wallet

Tags: account

Yesterday, I fell victim to a scam which resulted in the theft of my funds. As a precautionary measure, I have locked my wallet. However, upon attempting to access my Solana network via the Phantom wallet, I encountered an issue where the network appears to be disabled. Despite my efforts to re-enable it through the settings, I have been unsuccessful. How can I effectively reactivate the Solana network on my wallet?